# Pattern matching – Normalized Correlation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

as a part of my homework i need to implement this pattern matching.
the goal is to "Detect as many of the 0's (zeros) as you can in image coins4.tif."

 i was given the NGC function. and i need to use it

 this is my main.m file

```
Image = readImage('coins4.tif');
Pattern = readImage('zero.tif');
showImage(Image);
showImage(Pattern);
message = sprintf('Pattern matching Normalized Correlation');
PatternMatching(Image , Pattern);
uiwait(msgbox(message,'Done', 'help'));
close all
```

this is my PatternMatching function.

```
function [ output_args ] = PatternMatching( Image , Pattern )
% Pattern matching – Normalized Correlation
% Detect as many of the 0's (zeros) as you can in image coins4.tif.
% Use the 0 of the 10 coin as pattern.
% Use NGC_pm and find good threshold. Display original image with? detected regions marked using drawRect.

% NGCpm(im,pattern);
% drawRect(rectCoors,color);
% rectCoors = [r0,c0,rsize,csize]  - r0,c0 = top-left corner of rect.
%             rsize = number of rows, csize = number of cols
%
% color = an integer >=1 representing a color in the color wheel
%                   (curerntly cycles through 8 different colors

showImage(Image);
hold on
res = NGCpm(Image, Pattern);

 for i = 1:size(res,1)
     for j = 1:size(res,2)
         if res(i,j) > 0.9999
             drawRect([i j size(Pattern,1) size(Pattern,2)], 5)
         end
     end
 end

end
```

this is the Given NGCpm.m file

```
function res=NGC_PM(im,pattern)
[n m]=size(pattern);
[im_row,im_col]=size(im);
if ~(var(pattern(:))==0)
     res = normxcorr2(pattern, im);
     res=res(n:im_row,m:im_col);   
else
    res=zeros(size(im)-size(pattern)+1);
end;
 res = 1-abs(res);  % res = abs(res);
```

this is the pattern i'm trying to find and the results, i'm getting

i'm trying to find as many "Zeros" as possiable using the zero pattern of the coin 10.

i'm tryingto understand if there is something wrong with my algorithm in the PatternMatching function. since the NGCpm function is already given to me,  all i need to do is just loop of the best threshold ,correct? 

 or do i need to blur the image or the pattern?

[image: this is the pattern i'm trying to find]

[image: this is the image and the results]

Comment: What is the actual purpose of the homework ? To show that cross-correlation isn't adequate for this problem ? The pattern you have apparently was taken from the 10 cents coin, that is why you have the best matching there. If you want to possibly match the "0" in other coins using this method, you will need to somehow obtain a very good binary image (or an equally very clear grayscale image) for both the template and the input image.

Comment: @mmgp hello friend. the goal is to "Detect as many of the 0's (zeros) as you can in image coins4.tif.", in order to get the pattern i just cropped the image. and took the zero from the 10 cents coin. however i do not understand how will this help me find the zero of the 50 cents for example which is bigger, using this technique...

Comment: the function res=NGC_PM(im,pattern) was given. maybe i'm not using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the fixed version of this function.

```
function [ output_args ] = patternMatching( Image , Pattern )
% Pattern matching – Normalized Correlation
% Detect as many of the 0's (zeros) as you can in image coins4.tif.
% Use the 0 of the 10 coin as pattern.
% Use NGC_pm and find good threshold. Display original image with? detected regions marked using drawRect.

% NGCpm(im,pattern);
% drawRect(rectCoors,color);
% rectCoors = [r0,c0,rsize,csize]  - r0,c0 = top-left corner of rect.
%             rsize = number of rows, csize = number of cols
%
% color = an integer >=1 representing a color in the color wheel
%                   (curerntly cycles through 8 different colors

showImage(Image);
hold on
res = 1-NGCpm(Image, Pattern);
normalized_corellation = uint8(255*res/max(max(res)));
res_thresh = thresholdImage(normalized_corellation,100);
 for i = 1:size(res_thresh,1)
     for j = 1:size(res_thresh,2)
         if res_thresh(i,j) > 0
             drawRect([i j size(Pattern,1) size(Pattern,2)], 5)
         end
     end
 end

end
```